# Perl data parsing and inserting lines

Tags: perl, parsing

to Perl Masters in the world!

I have a file like this to parse and want to make......

starting from the first column, ID, exon information, start position, end position and direction. ID increases by 1 when it meets a number.

```
1   9239    712 8571    +
1   start_codon 712 714 +
1   stop_codon  8569    8571    +
2   3882    24137   24264   +
2   start_codon 24137   24139   +
3   3882    24322   24391   +
4   3882    24490   26064   +
4   stop_codon  26062   26064   +
5   4972    26704   26740   +
5   start_codon 26704   26706   +
6   4972    26814   27170   +
7   4972    27257   27978   +
7   stop_codon  27976   27978   +
8   10048   40161   41114   -
8   start_codon 41112   41114   -
8   stop_codon  40161   40163   -
9   272 43167   43629   -
9   stop_codon  43167   43169   -
10  272 43755   44059   -
10  start_codon 44057   44059   -
```

like this ....

```
1   9239    *712*   *8571*  +
1   start_codon 712 714 +
1   stop_codon  8569    8571    +
*X  9239    712 8571    +*
2   3882    *24137* 24264   +
2   start_codon 24137   24139   +
3   3882    24322   24391   +
4   3882    24490   *26064* +
4   stop_codon  26062   26064   +
*X  3882    24173   26064   +*
5   4972    *26704* 26740   +
5   start_codon 26704   26706   +
6   4972    26814   27170   +
7   4972    27257   *27978* +
7   stop_codon  27976   27978   +
*X  4972    26704   27978 +*
8   10048   *40161* *41114* -
8   start_codon 41112   41114   -
8   stop_codon  40161   40163   -
*X  10048   40161   41114   -*
9   272 *43167* 43629   -
9   stop_codon  43167   43169   -
10  272 43755   *44059* -
10  start_codon 44057   44059   -
*X  272 43167   44059   -*
```

each line begins with X has to be added but with my skill I cannot... :(

The thing is for every exon number in the second column ignoring the "start_codon" and "end_codon", have to get the minimum numbered exon position and maximum numbered exon position between asterisks *.

This is my basic code to parse the data... but I guess, have to re-code from the scratch
(I do not have any idea how to insert the line 'X')

(Sorry I deleted the code as its not so good enough and may give a confusion...)

Perl Masters in the World, Could you please help me???

Thank you!!

AS TLP aked I put my code back. Its embarrassing code though

```
use strict;

if (@ARGV != 1) {
    print "Invalid arguments\n";
    print "Usage: perl min_max.pl [exon_output_file]\n";
    exit(0);
}

my $FILENAME = $ARGV[0];
    my  $exonid = 0;
    my  $exon = "";
    my  $startpos = 0;
    my  $endpos = 0;
    my  $strand = "";
    my  $min_pos = 0;
    my  $max_pos = 0;

open (DATA, $FILENAME);

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;

    if ($line ne "") {
        if ($line =~ /^(.+)\t(.+)\t(.+)\t(.+)\t(.+)/) {
        $exonid = $1;
        $exon = $2;
        $startpos = $3;
        $endpos = $4;
        $strand = $5;
        }
        if ($exon =~ /\d+/) {
            print $exonid,"\t",$exon,"\t",$startpos,"\t",$endpos,"\t",$strand,"\n";
        } else {
            print $exonid,"\t",$exon,"\t",$startpos,"\t",$endpos,"\t",$strand,"\n";
        }
    }
}

close (DATA);
exit;
```

How can I compare the biggest value and the lowest value....

Comment: You have made no attempts to store the min/max values anywhere. How could that possibly work?

Comment: exactly, I was trying but I couldn't so I just put the most basic code to begin with I deleted all the parts that weren't working. I am still working on. Thats why the above code is so simple. thanx. :(

Comment: why `*X  10048   40161   41114   -*` not `*X  10048   41112 41114 -*` after 8 ?

Comment: ignoring the start_codon and the end_codon, Im looking for the smallest value and the biggest value for each numbered exoninformation. Thanx (Numbers in the second column are the exoninfo. )

Comment: What did you want `X` to be?

Comment: X to be just "X". I want the line starts with X to remark that its a new line. Thanx for a questions TLP.

Comment: You should also know that this is a Q&A site, you ask questions about your code. What you have done is post a problem and ask for the code.

Comment: I am trying by myself as well. But its not working. I will put up the basic structure once I get some idea. I just need to know how to create a new line X...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you do is go through the lines, skip the ones you don't want (i.e. no number in col 2), remember min/max for each new line in the same set, and when the col 2 number changes you print and start over. With this solution, you also have to print the last set manually at the end.

This code uses the internal `DATA` file handle for demonstration data. Simply change `<DATA>` to `<>` to use on a target input file like so: `perl script.pl inputfile`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(min max);

my $print;
my ($min, $max, $id);
while (<DATA>) {                   ###### change to <> to run on input file
    my @line = split;
    if ($line[1] !~ /^\d+$/) {                # if non-numbers in col 2
         print;                               # print line
         next;                                # skip to next line
    }
    if (!defined($id) or $id != $line[1]) {   # New dataset!
        say $print if $print;                 # Print and reset 
        $id = $line[1];
        $min = $max = undef;
    }
    $min = min($min // (), @line[2,3]);       # find min/max, skip undef
    $max = max($max // (), @line[2,3]);
    $print = join "\t", "X", $line[1], $min, $max;  # buffer the print
}
print $print;

__DATA__
1   9239    712 8571    +
1   start_codon 712 714 +
1   stop_codon  8569    8571    +
2   3882    24137   24264   +
2   start_codon 24137   24139   +
3   3882    24322   24391   +
4   3882    24490   26064   +
4   stop_codon  26062   26064   +
5   4972    26704   26740   +
5   start_codon 26704   26706   +
6   4972    26814   27170   +
7   4972    27257   27978   +
7   stop_codon  27976   27978   +
8   10048   40161   41114   -
8   start_codon 41112   41114   -
8   stop_codon  40161   40163   -
9   272 43167   43629   -
9   stop_codon  43167   43169   -
10  272 43755   44059   -
10  start_codon 44057   44059   -
```

**Output:**

```
9239    712     8571
3882    24137   26064
4972    26704   27978
10048   40161   41114
272     43167   44059
```

Comment: Thanx TLP for the help, but the output that I wanted was like the second box in my question. But reading thorugh you code will help me learning perl more. So I am glad and appreciate your help and time.

Comment: @Karyo That's just a matter of adding a `print` statement before the `next` statement, and then reformatting the `$print` variable. Unless you also wanted the `*` symbols around the min/max numbers.

Comment: Thanks TLP, your one works more generally!!!! but what do you mean by adding a print statement before the next statement? Sorry I don't get it :(

Comment: It's not rocket science. I mean adding the word `print` before the word `next`. :) I've made some small changes, you can study the version history of my post to see exactly what I did. Click the part where it says `edited X hours/minutes ago`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, here's one way (untested!) to do what you seem to be asking for:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# read first line, initialize accumulators, print it back
chomp($_ = <>);
my ($last_id, $last_exon, $min_start, $max_end, $last_strand) = split /\t/;
say $_;

# loop over remaining lines
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($exonid, $exon, $startpos, $endpos, $strand) = split /\t/;

    if ($exon !~ /\D/ and $exon != $last_exon) {
        # new exon found, print summary of last one...
        say join "\t", "X", $last_exon, $min_start, $max_end, $last_strand;
        # ...and reset accumulators
        ($last_id, $last_exon, $min_start, $max_end, $last_strand)
            = ($exonid, $exon, $startpos, $endpos, $strand);
    }
    else {
        # previous exon continues, just update accumulators
        $last_id     = $exonid;
        $last_exon   = $exon     if $exon !~ /\D/;
        $min_start   = $startpos if $min_start > $startpos;
        $max_end     = $endpos   if $max_end < $endpos;
        $last_strand = $strand;  # should not really be needed
    }
    # ...and don't forget to print the original line back again
    say $_;
}
# end of file, print summary of last exon
print join("\t", "X", $last_exon, $min_start, $max_end, $last_strand), "\n";
```

Basically, I'm assuming that you want to print a summary line starting with `X` whenever you encounter a number in the second column which is different from the previous number in that column, and that lines with non-numeric values in the second column should never trigger a summary.  Also, you'll presumably want a summary line at the end of the file, too.

The expression `$exon !~ /\D/` returns true if `$exon` contains only numbers.  (Specifically, it tests whether it *doesn't* contain a *non*-numeric character, so an empty string would match too.)

There are a bunch of edge cases that I haven't considered, since I don't know whether they're possible in your data and how you want to treat them if they do occur.  For example, just to be careful, one might wish to also print a summary in the unlikely event that the strand changes while the exon number stays the same.  Similarly, a careful programmer might want to consider the possibility of the input file being empty, or of the first line containing a non-numeric value in the second column.

At least with `use warnings` you'll be alerted if any of the values I assumed would always be numeric turn out not to be so.

Comment: Thanx llmari Karonen! This code is working great, but it doesn't print out the first line of the file "1 9239 712 8571 +" and starting with the second line. But thanx heaps I will manage to do the rest!

Comment: I've tried, but this time the first line printed twice. So Once I removed the 'say $_;' from the first chomp line, it worked perfect! Thanx heaps!